# How to move my profile from Google Account to Stack Exchange Account?

Tags: discussion, user-accounts, openid

I want to clean up my Google Account with OpenID and move my profile on Stack Exchange (where I sign in with Google Account) to Stack Exchange Profile.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 6):

1. Create an OpenID at https://openid.stackexchange.com/
2. Go to you profile page (https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/20021/loldop)
3. Click on the "my logins" link.
4. Click on the "add more logins..." link:

   [image]
5. Select "log in with Stack Exchange" and enter the details created at step 1.
6. Optionally remove the existing login by clicking on the little "x" that appears to right of the entry. NOTE: This might not appear if there's only one e-mail address.